# OpenCart Frete Gratis CEP

Tags: php, opencart

O cliente quer disponibilizar frete gratuito pra compras aqui na cidade, o opencart já tem opção de frete grátis por preço, quero só saber como faço pra fazer uma condição do cep daqui.

Quero saber quais arquivos editar e tal. E também como saber a faixa de cep aqui da cidade.

Comment: então, acho que ele não vai querer, mais não tem uma base dessa gratuita?

Comment: entendi, obrigado por enquanto. agora sobre o opencart você sabe algo? dos arquivos eu digo.

Comment: Achei isso aqui: http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/servicos/dnec/menuAction.do?Metodo=menuFaixaCep

Comment: Não entendo nada de OpenCart. :(

Comment: opa cara, obrigado, as vezes a gente não procura direto. a faixa de cep acho q ta certo. obrigado mesmo. agora só vou descobrir o arquivo aqui e fazer a validação

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
function busca_cep($cep){  
    $resultado = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?cep='.urlencode($cep).'&formato=query_string');  
    if(!$resultado){  
        $resultado = "&resultado=0&resultado_txt=erro+ao+buscar+cep";  
    }  
    parse_str($resultado, $retorno);   
    return $retorno;  
}  


/* 
 * Exemplo de utilização  
 */  

//Vamos buscar o CEP 90020022  
$resultado_busca = busca_cep('90020022');  

echo "<pre> Array Retornada: 
 ".print_r($resultado_busca, true)."</pre>";  

switch($resultado_busca['resultado']){  
    case '2':  
        $texto = " 
    Cidade com logradouro único 
    <b>Cidade: </b> ".$resultado_busca['cidade']." 
    <b>UF: </b> ".$resultado_busca['uf']." 
        ";    
    break;  

    case '1':  
        $texto = " 
    Cidade com logradouro completo 
    <b>Tipo de Logradouro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['tipo_logradouro']." 
    <b>Logradouro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['logradouro']." 
    <b>Bairro: </b> ".$resultado_busca['bairro']." 
    <b>Cidade: </b> ".$resultado_busca['cidade']." 
    <b>UF: </b> ".$resultado_busca['uf']." 
        ";  
    break;  

    default:  
        $texto = "Fala ao buscar cep: ".$resultado_busca['resultado'];  
    break;  
}  

echo $texto;  
?>
```

Comment: Creio que com esse exemplo você consiga entender melhor.